# jspdf doesn't return the entire html page to pdf

Tags: javascript, jspdf

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnIDu.png)I am trying to convert html page to PDF using JSPDF.The page is rendered in my screen with 65% resolution by default and upon converting this to PDF, it renders the PDF with a black strip on the right side of the generated PDF.
Resolving screen size to 100%, the black strip increases in thickness.

JSPDF method is applied to the entire div<> containing the page content.
Tried to fix the width of the content and page to adjust the content within the screen.

```
var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt','a4');
    pdf.page = 1;
    var totalPages=1;

    pdf.text("Report", 220, 22);// set your margins

    var str = "Page " + pdf.page  + " of " +  totalPages;
    pdf.setFontSize(9);// optional
    pdf.text(str, 250, pdf.internal.pageSize.height - 10);
    pdf.text("Confidential", 490, pdf.internal.pageSize.height - 10);
    pdf.internal.scaleFactor = 2.10;
    pdf.addHTML($('#reportTabContent')[0], 30, 30, {
        'height': 1750,
        'width': 1058, 
        background: '#fff', 
        pageSplit:'true'
      },function () {       
          pdf.save('Reports.pdf');
      });
```

I expect the HTML page as it is in PDF form.
But the jspdf is creating pdf of the html page with a black patch in the right side of the generated pdf. Please help.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSKEP.png)

Comment: javascript or java?

Comment: @barbsan let's tag it both, just to be safe... and annoy java users ;)

Comment: @barbsan javascript

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, the issue comes from the css code applied to that div, not the configuration with jsPdf. Can you also share you css code of that div?

Comment: css code is not applied to that div, I am sharing the html code applied to that div.

Comment: This is how I suggest you debug the code . Removing the component that render that chart, the css code for that chart may also affect jsPDF from rendering correctly. Try to check where the issue arises.

Answer (score 0):

remove the height and width in that code and page split in that code and trey once 
damn sure